# How to create an alias for an enum in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, enums, alias

In my project I have a set of auto generated enum types, which I include from. Their names are long and I would like to created aliases for them. Let's say I have some enums with the following names:

```
MySuperLongEnumName1
MyEvenLongerSuperLongEnumName2
```

Now throughout the project these enums are used everywhere, but I'd like to replace them by easier names, without changing the auto generated file.

What I have now is the following code (unfortunately, it is not working):

```
import { MySuperLongEnumName1 as Enum1 } from 'auto-generated-file.ts';
import { MyEvenLongerSuperLongEnumName2 as Enum2 } from 'auto-generated-file.ts';

export {
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
};
```

So I would import them simply using:

```
import { Enum1 } from 'types.ts';
```

TypeScript seems to accept them and even adds a note when hovering over the type saying it is an `alias`. But the app crashes while starting, saying it loaded the auto-generated file twice (already declared). This error goes away when I removed the `import / export` for the alias.

Comment: The full error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually working now the error in the other file has been resolved.